# can i use getRequest() in clicommands of zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2, icinga2

I'm using zendframework. Here i used `getRequest()` method outside the controller, inside the CliCommands class.But it through an error.

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
 V1Command::getRequest().
```

Is there any way to use the getRequest() outside the controller?

UPDATE:

After using this:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$all = $front->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Now I'm getting this type of error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getParams() on
>   null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside the controller you can use any one of these

```
$all = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$one = $this->getRequest()->getParam('key');

$all = $this->_request->getParams();
$one = $this->_request->getParam('key');

$all = $this->_getAllParams();
$one = $this->_getParam('key');
```

Or from outside the controller (and after the front controller is loaded):

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$all = $front->getRequest()->getParams();
$one = $front->getRequest()->getParam('key');
```